# ng-click in template not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having no luck figuring out why the ng-click isn't calling the function.  I am compiling the angular template.  I know I have an isolated scope, but the function That should be called is on the scope of the directive...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/101/)

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myMod">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <thead><th></th><th>Name</th></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="datum in data" my-element person ="datum"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

AngularJS(v1.28):

```
angular.module("myMod", []).
    controller("myController",
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.data = [
            { 'name' : 'testA', 'isAdmin': true},
            { 'name' : 'testB', 'isAdmin': false},
            { 'name' : 'testC', 'isAdmin': false},
        ];
}).directive("myElement",function($compile){

    var myTest = function(){
        console.log("table cell clicked!");
    };

    var getTemplate = function(person){
        return '<td><span ng-click="myTest()">{{person.name}}</span></td><td>test2</td>';
    };

return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            person : "="
        },
        link : function (scope,element,attrs){

            var template = getTemplate(scope.person);
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        } 
    };
```

});

Comment: Can you also include your HTML?

Comment: Is it because myTest is in your directive myElement, but the span isn't using the my-element tag?

Comment: Ah, okay, missed the JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is that you defined `myTest` to be a function that is not on the scope of the directive, hence the view is not aware of that function.

Just change it to be on the scope:

```
return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            person : "="
        },
        link : function (scope,element,attrs){

            scope.myTest = function(){
                console.log("table cell clicked!");
            };

            var template = getTemplate();
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);


        } 
    };
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11619/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the link

http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/103/

I have made the necessary changes and the code is working fine.

```
.directive("myElement",function($compile){
  var getTemplate = function(person){
    return '<td><span ng-click="myTest()">{{person.name}}</span></td><td>test2</td>';
  };

  return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            person : "="
        },
        link : function (scope,element,attrs){
          var template = getTemplate(scope.person);
          element.html(template);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);

       scope.myTest = function(){
        console.log("table cell clicked!");
      };
    } 
  };
});
```